# customer with multiple addresses

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set up a mysql database and a php script where a customer can add multiple addresses and set one address as default. A customer with multiple addresses can be realised like this:

[image]

But how should I change the diagram to store the default address? First, I was tempted to realise it with a boolean like this:

[image]

But this has the disadvantage that if the user wants to change his default address one needs to change two addresses, seeting one default_address to true and another to false. When something goes wrong this could lead to an inconsistent database where a user has no default address or more than one default addresses. Is there a more robust way to realise this?

Comment: `When something goes wrong this could lead to an inconsistent database` - you might benefit from describing how things can go wrong with this solution.

Comment: This is why you use transactions in a database. Either the entire update is performed, or none of it is.

Comment: @Boaz I just think it is fragile for anomalies. Isn't that the same why people do database normalization?

Comment: You could have a table of default addresses whose columns are `idcustomer` and `idaddress`.

Comment: @Barmar I think that is still fragile for anomalies. Here I could have a entry in (idcustomer,idaddress) in table of default addresses where a customer_idcustomer and id_customer are different

Comment: How could that happen? I understand in the original scenario that there could be an interruption between removing one default flag and adding it to another record, so you get 0 or multiple defaults. But what kind of anomaly would assign the default to the wrong customer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a default_address_id field in the customer table.

Comment: Then it could happen that idcustomer and the customer_idcustomer of the corresponding address of the default_address_id is not the same.

Comment: At which point you'll likely be having a bigger mess already. I can't think of a single solution where you don't rely on IDs, which you currently expect to change at some point in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Eran's solution, in conjunction with some JOIN query, or add a table default_cst_addresses containing customer_id, address_id and then reference those via relations to the other tables.